# Printing a string backwards

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to print a string in reverse. i.e.

```
hello world
```

should come out as:

```
 dlrow olleh
```

But the outcome only shows the reverse of the first word. i.e.

```
 olleh
```

Any thoughts?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input a string:"); 
        String s;
        s = input.next();

        String original, reverse = "";

        original = s;

        int length = original.length();

        for ( int i = length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
            reverse = reverse + original.charAt(i);

        System.out.println("Reverse of entered string is: "+reverse);
        input.close();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug your program. Start with some simple prints to see why it's doing what it's doing.

Comment: What does `s = input.next();` do?

Comment: `s = input.next();` gets a user imputed string

Comment: @Cullen Read the documentation and see what *specifically* it retrieves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `input.next()` only stores the next word in the variable (only "hello"). Try this:

```
    System.out.println("Input a string:");
    String s;
    s = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("entered: " + s);
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

> s=input.next()

will only take one word.

So to get the whole line 'hello world', you've to use the nextLine() function.

```
s = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your scanner object returns only the next complete token through the input.next() method. A token is considered complete when there is a whitespace character. Use the nextLine() method of the scanner to get the complete input if you are using multiple words.

Answer (score 1):

```
  new StringBuilder("hello world").reverse().toString();
```

Maybe much more simpler.

Answer (score 1):

use s.nextline() instead of s.next() as s.next() read only first token string

```
     Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `s = input.next()` to `s = input.nextLine()`

Comment: First of all read the whole input line from the user. He is only reading the first word.

Comment: @SeahawksRdaBest Don't you think this information should be part of your answer? Giving solution and explaining problem are two different things.

Comment: Honestly I wanted him/her to google the difference. I believe finding information on your own helps the most. Knowing how to look up java and android libraries is essential for any coder.

Comment: Then what purpose does your answer serve?

Comment: didn't give the answer but told him where to look.

Answer (score 0):

From [Scanner javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> `public String next()`
>
> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A
>   complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the
>   delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to
>   scan, even if a previous invocation of `hasNext()` returned true.

What happens is that the token delimiter may not be what you're expecting (newline, for instance).

If you wish your program to read the entire line input by the user, you might want to use [`Scanner.nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29), which will read the entire line input by the user, or maybe [`Scanner.next(String delimiter)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28java.lang.String%29), which will allow you to enter the desired token delimiter.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really write some source code but maybe try using two different inputs. After that add each string to it's own variable. After that, reverse them both and add them together as an output.